# Divide the space for two views depending on Percentage

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uiview, autolayout

So I have a view:

[image]

I have the two views in a stack view, using the storyboard.

I get two value  in the viewController, and I want each of the view size to correspond at the percentage they represent of the sum of both of them.

ex: the size of the stackview is 100, if I get 700 and 300, the view size will be 70 and 30

Thanks

Comment: @rbaldwin yes I do

Comment: @rbaldwin using Storyboard

Comment: @rbaldwin no I get like two values ex 2500 and 3600, and I have to size the both view relatively of the values I get. Like if the whole stackview would be 100% and then the two cumulated would be the whole stackview

Comment: Can you update your question, to clarify that please.

Comment: Sure. It would be great if you could bring me some help

Comment: @Cublax - you said *"using Storyboard"* but you also said  *"I get like two values ex 2500 and 3600"* ... where / when are you getting those two values?

Comment: @DonMag I get those 2 values in the ViewController, and I have to resize the two views depending on the ratio each of them represent on their sum

Comment: @Cublax https://jasmine-elamblakatt.medium.com/weight-assignment-in-stack-view-percentage-wise-size-calculation-37ee0591bf1e   
check this article its also may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Storyboard:

- put the two views in a stack view
- set stack view to

  - Axis: Vertical
  - Alignment: Fill
  - Distribution: Fill
  - Spacing: 0 (or whatever spacing you want)
- give the stack view:

  - Top / Bottom / Leading / Trailing constraints
  - or Width, Height and position constraints
- Ctrl-drag from the bottom view to the top view
- Select Equal Heights, with Multiplier of 1 (doesn't matter, as it will be changed in code)

In your view controller, create an `@IBOutlet` to that constraint, such as:

```
@IBOutlet var proportionalHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Here's how it looks in Storyboard:

[image]

We cannot directly change the multiplier, so add this extension to your project:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

    static func setMultiplier(_ multiplier: CGFloat, of constraint: inout NSLayoutConstraint) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([constraint])

        let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: constraint.firstItem as Any, attribute: constraint.firstAttribute, relatedBy: constraint.relation, toItem: constraint.secondItem, attribute: constraint.secondAttribute, multiplier: multiplier, constant: constraint.constant)

        newConstraint.priority = constraint.priority
        newConstraint.shouldBeArchived = constraint.shouldBeArchived
        newConstraint.identifier = constraint.identifier

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([newConstraint])
        constraint = newConstraint
    }

}
```

In `viewDidLoad()` (or whenever you get your two values):

```
class CubiaxViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var proportionalHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let top: CGFloat = 3600
        let bottom: CGFloat = 2500

        NSLayoutConstraint.setMultiplier(bottom / top, of: &proportionalHeightConstraint)

    }

}
```

Here's how it looks at runtime with:

```
    let top: CGFloat = 3600
    let bottom: CGFloat = 2500
```

[image]

Here's how it looks with:

```
    let top: CGFloat = 700
    let bottom: CGFloat = 300
```

[image]

Here's how it looks with:

```
    let top: CGFloat = 200
    let bottom: CGFloat = 1500
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your two `UIViews` in your `UIStackView` (vertical axis)
2. Create an `IBOutlet` for your UIStackView
3. Create an `IBOutlet` for your top `UIView`
4. Set the `UIStackView` distribution to `fillEqually` in Storyboard to silence warnings.
5. In your code calculate the ratio of the top view
6. Set the `UIStackView` distribution to fill
7. Set the height multiplier of the top view in relation to the `UIStackView`

---

The code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var topView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let topHeight: CGFloat = 700.0
        let bottomHeight: CGFloat = 300.0

        let topViewRatio = topHeight / (topHeight + bottomHeight)

        stackView.distribution = .fill
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor, multiplier: topViewRatio).isActive = true
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are those views into a UIStackView? If so, you just need to put a constraint on their heights.

Make `view1.height = *multiplier* x view2.height`.

You can easily calculate the multiplier out of your percentage, as `multiplier = percentage2 / percentage1`.

So in your example `multiplier = 50 / 50 = 1`. If you want, say, 30%/70% make the `multiplier = 70 / 30 = 2.333`.

Comment: I don't get it, let say topView value is 201600 and bottom view = 50400. What do you concretely write. Because it isn't working and I don't get where is the problem. Also the problem is that already you access it like so topView.frame.size.height, and the mutiplier doesn't work unless it's a CGPoint